# Convex n-sided polygons whose exterior angles expressed in degrees are in arithmetic progression

Tags: geometry, diophantine-equations, polygons, arithmetic-progressions

If the exterior angles of a convex n-sided polygon, are all integers, expressed in degrees, are in arithmetic progression, how many values are possible for $n$?

The sum of all exterior angles has to be 360°.

So, the total number of factors of $360$° are $24$. Subtracting $2$ factors ( $1$ & $2$ ), all the other factors can easily represent the number of sides of polygons.

So, on the whole, why can't be there $22$ polygons having all exterior angles in $AP$, and integer?

Comment: @JeanMarie What is the sum of all external angles of any n-sided polygon? 360° right?

Comment: The OP probably means exterior angles. Whose sum is in fact 360°. Leading to a Diophantine equation for $a_0$, $n$ and $\Delta a$.

Comment: Any regular polygon has its exterior angles in arithmetic progression (with difference $0$). Do you consider that a valid case? If you do, the question is trivial.

Comment: @Jean Marie I think that by external he means exterior - complimentary to 180. It is than 90X4 = 360

Comment: @jjagmath I do not think he refers to the trivial case.

Comment: @Lakshay are you talking about arithmetic or geometric? If arithmetic, factors not relevant.

Comment: @Intelligenci Pauca Thanks. Exterior is indeed the right word. The OP should have a look for example at the excellent reference [here](https://www.learnalberta.ca/content/memg/Division03/Exterior%20Angle%20(of%20a%20Polygon)/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit: I just realized that I hadn't answered in a convenient way to the question which looks for values of $n$. Here is a re-writing of my solution.**

First remark: we **do not** exclude the case of regular polygons ("regular" with the meaning "equal external angles").

The well known expression of the terms of an Arithmetic Progression is $a+bk$ for given constants $a,b$, variable $k$ taking values $0,1, \cdots$ (here parameters $a\ge 0,b \ge 0$ are integers; had we wanted to exclude regular polygons, we should have taken $b > 0$).

Therefore, we must have, for a $n$-gon,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (a+bk)=360$$

Otherwise said:

$$na+b \frac12 n(n+1)=360 \iff n(2a+b(n+1))=720 \ \text{with} \ 720=2^4.3^2.5\tag{1}$$

We have to solve this equation understood as the existence of integers $a \ge 0,b \ge 0,n>0$ fulfilling it.

The values of $n$ have to be chosen among the $(4+1) \times (2+1)\times (1+1)=30$ divisors of $720$:

$$n \in \{1, \ 2,\ 3,\ 4,\ 5,\ 6,\ 8,\ 9,\ 10,\ 12,\ 15,\ 16,\ 18,\ 20,\ 24,\ 30,\ 36,\ 40,\ 45
,\ 48,\ 60,\ 72,\ 80,\ 90,\ 120,\ 144,\ 180,\ 240, \ 360, \ 720 \}$$

with pairs of complementary divisors: $(1,720), (2,360), (3,240)....$ that I will call "twins" in the following.

(in fact only $27$ of them can be used: because polygons with $n=1, \ 2$ aren't polygons and polygon with 720 vertices has 720 sides, and would generate non integer external angles).

Let us browse all possible values of $n$ and attempt to solve (1) :

- $n=3:$ twined with $240$ gives $(2a+4b)=240$ which has (many) solutions: therefore $n=3$ is eligible.
- $n=4:$ twined with $180$ is eligible because (1) gives $2a+5b=180$ which has solutions.
- $n=5:$ is eligible because (1) gives $2a+6b=144$ which has solutions ($a=0,b=24$ for example).
- etc. etc.
- an impossibility occurs for $n=48, n=80, n=144, n=240$ because none of the corresponding equations $2a+49b=15, \ 2a+81b=9, \ 2a+145b=5, 2a+241 b=3$ resp.  have nonnegative solutions.

This rules out four values for $n$.

Therefore the answer is that there are $27-4=23$ possible values of $n$.

You have suggested that the answer could/should be $22$, i.e., one less. I must have a closer look and see if I haven't "lost" a case...

[image]

*Fig. 1: An example: A graphical representation of the solution $n=8, a=0, b=10$ with external angles $10°, 20°, 30°, \cdots 80°$ in Arithmetic Progression.*

**Remark 1:** A discussion should take place about the sidelengths of the polygon, for which there is a large "degree of freedom".

**Remark 2:** about the adjective "external" (vs. exterior) angles see [here](https://www.learnalberta.ca/content/memg/Division03/Exterior%20Angle%20(of%20a%20Polygon)/index.html).

Comment: Mathematica gives a total of 133 solutions.

Comment: Nicely presented!

Comment: @Moti Thanks...

Comment: @JeanMarie Flawless. My book has presented a wrong answer to this, ( it says 18 ). But, after reading your answer I can clearly say that indeed the author is wrong. Thank you. This is the most logical fit I could've ever hoped for.

Comment: Thanks for your thanks and thanks for this interesting question...

Comment: A triangle with equal angles does have not have to regular (unless it is a triangle), as it can have unequal sides like a rectangle.  Only some $n$ will give integer angles.  I do not see why these are excluded.

Comment: You must mean "a n-gon with equal angles does not have to be regular." I don't think I have said that "equal angles imply equal sides" (which is indeed false, but for triangle, as you say it).

Comment: @JeanMarie  n=8,a=10,b=0 does not satisfy the above equation which you have written

Comment: You are right, I have exchanged $a$ and $b$ : $a=0$ and $b=10$. Thank you. I fix it.

Comment: @JeanMarie   Do I need to put each and every value (30 values, although can eliminate n=1,2, and 720) of n  and check if I can find any positive integer solutions for a and b ? that would be such a humongous task, is there any other way to find it quickly? like if I assume them to be regular polygons , there would be 22 solutions for that, so for the ones which aren't regular is there any way to find the number of those cases to arrive at answer.

Comment: @Fin27 See my re-edition of the answer.

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks a lot for putting in efforts for re-editing your answer and making it more clearer, kudos

Comment: I appreciate your thanks. Reciprocally, a lot of thanks for having spotted that I hadn't answered the real question, triggering this almost complete re-editing.