# Convex sided polygon with exterior angles in AP

Tags: polygons, arithmetic-progressions

This question has been asked before, but I have doubts regarding the answer given and being accepted over there : (Link :- [Convex n-sided polygons whose exterior angles expressed in degrees are in arithmetic progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4304902/convex-n-sided-polygons-whose-exterior-angles-expressed-in-degrees-are-in-arithm))

**Question:-**
If the exterior angles of a convex n-sided polygon, are all integers, expressed in degrees, are in arithmetic progression, how many values are possible for n?

**My approach:-**

360 has 24 factors , since no. of sides of a polygon >=3, therefore values of n possible will be 24-2 =22, The answer being accepted over there counters this argument by taking n=3, and providing various cases for exterior angles to be in AP {(120,120,120),(119,120,121) . . .} , but that is not a point to be taken at all, as we are only focused on the value of n and not on how many exterior angles are possible for a particular value of n.

Please let me know what is wrong in my approach ?

Comment: @StinkingBishop A $360$-gon with equal angles does not have to be regular, in the same way that a rectangle is not a square.

Comment: @Henry You are of course right. I will rework my comment above.

Comment: If I understand correctly the discussion in the linked question, then. (a) If you allow for all angles equal (i.e. the arithmetic progression with difference 0), then the answer is (correctly, but trivially) 22. If you don't, then the answer is potentially smaller than 22 because some values of n may force it to have all angles equal. (E.g. n=360 can only yield a polygon with all external angles of $1^\circ$.)

Comment: [I am the author of the referred answer] **You are fully right:** I hadn't paid enough attention to the question, and my answer was addressing another question. I just re-wrote this answer to comply with the real question. I have still to work on it...